# Updating MySQL table with JDBC issue

Tags: mysql, jdbc, sql-update

I have a piece of software where data gets inserted into a table, unless the data exists, in which case the table should get updated.
Inserting the data into the table causes no problems at all. I use the following code for that:

```
PreparedStatement ps = this.con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO tbl_banned(banned_player, banned_reason, banned_by, banned_from, banned_to) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
ps.setString(1, player.getName());
ps.setString(2, reason);
ps.setString(3, by);
ps.setString(4, currentDateTime);
ps.setString(5, toDateTime);

ps.executeUpdate();
```

However, when I try to update the same table with the same information using the following code:

```
PreparedStatement ps = this.con.prepareStatement("UPDATE tbl_banned SET banned_reason=?, SET banned_by=?, SET banned_from=?, SET banned_to=? WHERE banned_player=?");
ps.setString(1, reason);
ps.setString(2, by);
ps.setString(3, currentDateTime);
ps.setString(4, toDateTime);
ps.setString(5, player.getName());

ps.executeUpdate();
```

I get the following error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET banned_by='User', SET banned_from='2013/06/12 04:10:45', SET banned_to='2' at line 1
```

I can not seem to figure out what the reason is for this error, and I have been struggling with it for the past hour. If anybody could shed some light on the subject, that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no need to set multiple time in a row. it should be :

```
PreparedStatement ps = this.con.prepareStatement("UPDATE tbl_banned SET banned_reason=?,  banned_by=?, banned_from=?, banned_to=? WHERE banned_player=?");
```

[here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)  is your guidance to use UPDATE command in mysql

Comment: Thanks, it works! I never had a problem with this before though. I have some similar scripts where I use `SET` multiple times in a row and that causes no errors. I wonder why that is...